# Oracle puzzle: Selecting from a non-existing table

Tags: oracle

I have a table named `"libisatz"` in my database, and there is no table, nor view with name `"libiSatz"` (with capital S instead of s) and I don't find any kind of object in my schema having name `"libiSatz"`. But, surprisingly selecting from `"libiSatz"` results in the same result as if I had written `"libisatz"`. If I change any other letter in this name from lower case to upper case (e.g. I write `"Libisatz"`, then I get an error. How can this be?.

ADDENDUM

I've checked the ideas of @Jon Heller with the following result:

1. Both `select * from DBA_OBJECTS where OBJECT_NAME like 'libi_atz';` and `select * from DBA_OBJECTS where lower(OBJECT_NAME) = 'libisatz';` returns one single row (it is the `"libisatz"` table)
2. `select * from DBA_OBJECTS where OBJECT_NAME = 'libisatz';` returns one row and `select * from DBA_OBJECTS where OBJECT_NAME = 'libiSatz';` returns no row.
3. Both `select * from DBA_SQL_TRANSLATIONS;` and `select * from DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE;` results in `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`
4. `select * from DBA_REWRITE_EQUIVALENCES;` results in `no rows selected`
5. `select DUMP(OBJECT_NAME) from DBA_OBJECTS where lower(OBJECT_NAME) = 'libisatz';` returns `Typ=1 Len=8: 108,105,98,105,115,97,116,122`

So it seems that the puzzle is not yet solved.

ADDENDUM 2.

1. When I try to create a view named `"libiSatz"` then I get

   `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object`

   in spite of the results above.
2. After I renamed `"libiSatz"` to `"oraclepuzzle"`,

   `select count(*) from "libisatz";` and `"select count(*) from "oraclepuzzle";` works, but `select count(*) from "libiSatz";` doesn't.

   `select * from dba_objects where object_name in ( 'oraclepuzzle', 'libisatz', 'libiSatz');` returns one row with object_name `"oraclepuzzle"`.

Comment: Maybe a synonym? What does `select * from all_objects where lower(object_name) = 'libisatz'` give you?

Comment: This results in only one row (the table with lower case)

Comment: See answer from @TenG, but also note my response to same.

Comment: I was wondering it it could be a synonym; however, they appear in the `ALL_OBJECTS` table so if you've only got 1 row in the table then its not a synonym.

Comment: I know by now you have tried many things. But still I want to know which client tool are you using to access the tool? And what is the exact query you are trying to execute ?

Comment: This seems to me to be client and query independent. For example, in SQL* Plus Worksheet the select count(*) from .... query produces the phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SQL translations, rewrite equivalances, or UTF8 characters?

The **SQL translation framework** was built to allow applications designed for other database types to seamlessly query Oracle. But instead of translating syntaxes, the feature could also be used to silently change your queries. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22471046/409172) is an example of querying a table that does not exist in order to workaround table size limitations. Check the view `DBA_SQL_TRANSLATIONS`.

**Rewrite equivalences** can be created by the package `DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE`, and can be used to silently change the results of wrong queries or for some rare performance problems. (In my simple tests I wasn't able to get this query to work for invalid queries, but I bet there is a way to make it work.) Check the view `DBA_REWRITE_EQUIVALENCES`.

**UTF8 characters** may be silently swapped out for similar ASCII characters. This probably depends on your database and client character set settings. The below example is pretty obviously not an ASCII "S", but you may have a more subtle problem. Check the source of your values, retype them manually, and use the `DUMP` function to evaluate the binary of the characters.

```
SQL> create table "libisatz"(a number);

Table created.

SQL> -- An uppercase "S" does not work
SQL> select * from "libiSatz";
select * from "libiSatz"
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> -- But a "LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON" works.
SQL> select * from "libišatz";

no rows selected
```

Lastly, are you 100% sure that the object doesn't exist on your database? The above examples are possible, but extremely rare. Triple-check `DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_NAME` for the mystery object.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! Unfortunately, none of them solves the puzzle, see the addendum in the post.

Answer (score -2):

My deafult Oracle object names are case insensitive.

So, when you issue teh command:

`CREATE TABLE the_table ..`

`CREATE TABLE The_Table ..`

`CREATE TABLE THE_TABLE ..`

The underlying object name in all cases is `THE_TABLE`, but you can access it using any mix of upper/lower case:

`SELECT * FROM THE_TABLE`

`SELECT * FROM tHe_TaBlE`

`SELECT * FROM the_table`

Will all work.

When a table is created with the name wrapped in double-quotes, the name becomes case-sensitive.

So, if you issue:

`CREATE TABLE "libiSatz" ..`

Then the table name in all SQL statements must match the exact name in the double quotes, i.e.

`SELECT * FROM "libiSatz"` is OK (*Correction* following comments)

`SELECT * FROM libisatz` is NOT OK

`SELECT * FROM LibiSatz` is NOT OK

When you search for this in `USER_OBJECTS` or `USER_TABLES` you will have to match the creation name:

`SELECT * FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'libiSatz';`

Comment: Slight correction.  After creating the table with a case sensitive name, the statement  'SELECT * FROM libiSatz' is _not_ OK.  Because oracle will automaticly parse it as LIBISATZ.  Once you create an object name in mixed case the _only_ way to get oracle to recognize it is to enclose it in double-quotes _exactly_ like it was created.  This is why mixed-case names in oracle is a shockingly bad idea.  This ain't MSSQL.

Comment: The question is why `select * from "libiSatz"` and `select * from "libisatz"` are both OK while `select * from "liBisatz"` or `select * from "LibiSatz"` aren't. With special regards to the single row result for `select * from all_objects where lower(object_name) = 'libisatz'`

Comment: The second half of this answer is incorrect. If you use `CREATE TABLE "libiSatz"` then you need to use quotes in the select `SELECT * FROM "libiSatz"`. If you try without the quotes then the table will not be found. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9f2f6fc77691211f494a19815e77138)

Comment: Correction made.